# Data tables works in div?

Tags: html, css, datatable

Im using datatables in my site for most of the tables. I have done but the design is not so good even in responsive view. if i use div instead of table then datatable will work or not.. If anybody had the solution share me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle with a detailed description of exactly how it's messing up for you?

Comment: its not messing. i'm flexible with <div> elements but i'm really wired using table. i need a design something like this https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3bA6chkHPL

Comment: first problem i cant set background color or padding for table row, and need to write media queries for responsive table to make it scroll / flexible.

Comment: What is the URI of the fiddle? The "Collaboration" link doesn't really show anything.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think divs with display properties behave differently from tables. Tables rows don't have padding, but they do have background color. This is the same whether you use `<tr>` or `<div style="display:table-row">`.